# Image CSS Colliding With Other CSS - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have the following code:

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
  width: 460px;
  height: 430px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px) !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

img1 {
  width: 560px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #3EDD84;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
```

```html
<div class="column1">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask">
        <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
        <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>

        <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I am actually looking for the output in the above code - that is my expected output - but here is the problem:

I cannot seem to figure out which classes in the `css` file are colliding with each other and so the output I am getting on my screen is:

[image]

I do not want that, see how the image doesn't fit the box like in the code I sent above?

### Expected Output

The output in the code I sent above

What I tried: I made a separate image class and added the image URL in there so that I would know that other `<img>` is not colliding with this class, but when I ran my code, I would not get the image to show up. So I removed it. Is there any other way? I also set the `mask{` class to `!important` but it still would not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: For the code that isn't working, is there CSS from another file that is colliding with what you have provided? If so, we'd need to see that other CSS.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the `img` element in dev tools? In there (for common browsers) you can see the various CSS rules that are being applied to it and which ones are taking precedence using the 'Computed' tab.

Comment: So I searched my css for `mask` to see if I used it anywhere else too, but I cannot find it. The `mask` is for the image dimensions and so its not colliding with other css so I do not know why I am getting that output. I am unsure for the rest of the css since I checked and couldn't find it

Comment: @Bladeski where is the computed tab located?

Comment: This may be useful - [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/computed-values-more-than-meets-the-eye/)